# How to config "--allow-insecure-localhost" and "--ignore-certificate-errors"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, chromium

I'm not behind any company proxy, I'm just sitting at home but need to tell VSC/debugger to ignore insecure localhost, and certificate errors (assuming its effect is on my VSC only)

According to [SSL Certificates of VSC Setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_ssl-certificates) and [Run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags), `--allow-insecure-localhost` command-line flag, adding to the property of Chrome, Target, still not helping. How do I tell VSC to `--ignore-certificate-errors`?